# Resize popup window using javascript in chrome and set focus back to previous window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to open a popup window in on click of a button following is my code

```
function openPop(urld){
    myWindow=window.open(urld,'','width=300','height=500,left=0,top=100,screenX=0,screenY=100');
    if(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1)
        var t = setTimeout("resize(myWindow)", 200);
    else
        resize(myWindow);
}
function resize(window) {
    var innerWidth = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    var innerHeight = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
    var targetWidth = 500;
    var targetHeight = 500;
    window.resizeBy(targetWidth-innerWidth, targetHeight-innerHeight);
}
```

window is opening but height is not setting on chrome browser and how to set focus back to my previous window.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass parameter to the callback function (`resize(window)`) of `setTimeout`.

Change this line:

```
var t = setTimeout("resize(myWindow)", 200);
```

To this:

```
var t = setTimeout(function() { resize(myWindow); }, 200);
```